# Django User-Specific objects via ForeignKey

Tags: python, html, django, oop, foreign-keys

I am trying to implement a user-specific Shopping Cart, which looks like:

```
class Cart (models.Model):  
    items = []
    totalprice = 0
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
           related_name="cart", null=True)
```

I have an HTML template that will display an Item and allow the current user to add it to their cart:

```
<ul>
<img src={{ item.pic.url }}>
<li>{{ item.name }}</li>
<li>{{ item.desc }}</li>
<li>${{ item.cost }}</li>
</ul>
<br>
<a href={% url 'gallery:add_to_cart' item.id %}>Add to Cart</a>
```

The add_to_cart function is:

```
def add_to_cart (request, id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if not request.user.cart.all():
            c = Cart()
            c.save()
            request.user.cart.add(c)
        request.user.cart.all()[0].addItem(Item.objects.get(id=id))
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/gallery/')
```

Everything works fine for the first user, but once the first user logs out and another user logs in, their carts seem to be intertwined. Django will create a Cart for the second user, but this Cart will not initialize as empty; it will have the same contents as the Cart of the first user.

Upon adding any item to the Cart as the second user, that item will be added to both Carts, and their contents will be identical.

[Active "Cart" objects upon adding an Item as the second user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDvRb.png)

In short, I can't differentiate between individual users when accessing their Carts. Is there something I can do? I am thankful for any advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`items`** is a *mutable* object that is bound to the **`Cart`** class itself, **not** to a specific Cart Instance.  When you add an item to **`items`**, it will remain there as long as your server process it alive, or until you remove them manually.

Instead what you want is a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) that references your **`Item`** model:

```
class Cart (models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
           related_name="cart", null=True)
   
    items = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.Item')
```

Now in your view, your query would look something like this:

```
def add_to_cart (request, id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        cart.items.add(id)
    
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Cart` has fields which are python objects, not database items. So it just changes the object in python. You want:

```
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    totalprice = models.IntegerField()
```

This means that `items` and `totalprice` are now stored in the database alongside the `User` foreignkey. After making this change, be sure to `makemigrations` and `migrate` your database.